# MySQL not using index WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-in

I have a simple SELECT query that's using WHERE IN across 5 integer values to get 50 results in a table of roughly 20 million rows. Here's the query:

```
select `prf_profiles_id` as `id`, `first`, `last`, `suffix` from `prf_names`
where prf_names`.`src_sources_id` in (9, 10, 11, 34, 37) limit 50 offset 0;
```

And the explain values for the query:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: prf_names
type: ALL
possible_keys: prf_names_src_sources_id_index
key: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 20012960
Extra: Using where
```

As can be seen, the query knows the index is possible, but chooses not to use it and as a result the query takes about 4.5 seconds.

`src_sources_id` is indexed, and contains about 20 distinct values applied to all 20 million rows.

I know that the index would help immensely because when I run the same query using FORCE INDEX:

```
select `prf_profiles_id` as `id`, `first`, `last`, `suffix` from `prf_names`
force index (prf_names_src_sources_id_index)
where `prf_names`.`src_sources_id` in (9, 10, 11, 34, 37) limit 50 offset 0;
```

The query takes under 0.0 seconds.

I'd like to avoid forcing MySQL to use the index as the query is being called through an ORM and forcing it would defeat some of the purpose of having the ORM in the first place.

What can I do to ensure MySQL uses this index going forward?

### **EDIT:**

Here's the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `prf_names` (
`prf_profiles_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`verified` datetime NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`first` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`middle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`last` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`suffix` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sanitized` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
`src_sources_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`prf_profiles_id`,`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `prf_names_id_unique` (`id`),
KEY `prf_names_first_index` (`first`),
KEY `prf_names_middle_index` (`middle`),
KEY `prf_names_last_index` (`last`),
KEY `prf_names_src_sources_id_index` (`src_sources_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31633081 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you show us your table and index definition (show create table prf_names)? Also, is src_sources_id an int column?

Comment: There's [index hinting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: How many rows are in the result set?

Comment: Statistically seen the selectivity isn't that great. 5 out of about 20 means about 25% of the whole table. That may be sufficient for MySQL to consider the full table scan as faster than using the index. I wonder about your LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY. This may be the cause why the use of the index get the performance boost. The table scan needs probably some time to find those first 50 rows. I would consider using FORCE INDEX as appropriate then.

Comment: I've added in the table and index definition. The lack of an order by is because there's no reason to force a sort. It's to give the end user a sample of what the full result set is.

Comment: @MarcusAdams With the set LIMIT it's 50.

Comment: If it's only to give end users a sample, why don't you omit simply the WHERE clause? The query will be fast even without using an index becaue of the LIMIT optimization.

Comment: For some reason, the EXPLAIN plan doesn't take into count the LIMIT optimization. It's unknown how few rows is required to trigger index usage. It's especially hard to tell why MySQL is choosing not to use the index without more information, such as the schema.

Comment: @VMai The where clause is needed since each user is sandboxed to this set of data. Almost every table contains that column, and almost any query run against the database will contain a similar WHERE IN statement.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Unfortunately, I don't feel comfortable sharing the schema, however I would be interested in knowing how the layout of the rest of the information would affect this query.

Comment: In general, MySQL scans rows instead of using an index because there is still a cost in then looking up the actual record from the index. If you create a multi-column "covering index" that can be used to return all values in your result set, MySQL will likely use it. Ensure you put `src_sources_id` first in the index since it's what you're searching on.